# Facing issue in Cordova Android while integrate sign-in with MSAL

Tags: cordova, azure-active-directory, cordova-plugins, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a Cordova app where I am planned to integrate the MSAL library for Authentication. So I have created an custom cordova plugin with the msal library also with the help of the below tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android

Here based no the configuration I have added the below `BrowserTabActivity` activity in the plugin's **config.xml** to inject in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="application">
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="msauth"
                    android:host="$Package_Name"
                    android:path="/$Signature_Hash" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </config-file>
```

But while build the app for Android, the generated **AndroidManifest.xml** file doesn't have the `intent-filter`. It simply have the below tag only:

```
<activity android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"/>
```

For that reason while I Instantiate the **PublicClientApplication** class at that time it throws the below error, and suggest to add it in the AndroidManifest file.

> Intent filter for: BrowserTabActivity is missing.

Anyone developed the same for Cordova app and the facing similar problems? Any help...

**Note:** I tried the below cordova plugin also for the msal, but still I am facing the issue in Android and can't initiate the sign-in.
https://github.com/wrobins/cordova-plugin-msal

Comment: Are you able to integrate MSAL in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that another plugin (cordova-universal-links-plugin in our case) was removing the intent from the BrowserTabActivity

Comment: I suggest it would have been better to have added this in the comment session than providing this as an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).